# Does the Raspberry Pi 4 speaks Bluetooth aptX-HD?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, pi-4, audio-playback

I'd like to use a RPi 4 as a bluetooth audio receiver. For optimal sound quality I'd like to transmit the audio using Bluetooth aptX-HD. Can the built-in bluetooth receiver from the RPi 4 receive that? Or do I need to buy a separate Bluetooth receiver?

Comment: ... With the aptx website! Nothing for raspberry :-( Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APTX is a proprietary codec so I think it is unlikely. I would just mention that unless you are using it as a source for bluetooth headphones you would be much better off using it as a wifi/ethernet streamer as opposed to bluetooth. Even the best bluetooth codecs are extremely lossy, whereas LAN based transports like DLNA/RAAT/Squeezelite/chromecast/airplay transmit losslessly. Chromecast and Airplay will downsample audio with high sample rates, but the others will easily transmit bit-perfect audio at 24/192

EDIT--

In reviewing your question I have noted that you had intended to use this as as a receiver and not a source, so you can disregard the bit about BT headphones. Also, I should mention that Airplay is purportedly switching their support from 24/44.1 24/192 beginning June 2021 (i.e. now).

Comment: Thanks for the reply (even though it was a bit too late for me)!